# How to set json data into a html table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i want to display these json data into a html table. i am trying to do many things but i cant figure out how can i do it. So anyone can please help me to fix it. 
the json data set will appear in the console. but i cant set it to a table.

this is my model

```
public function displayRecords()
{
    $this->db->select('A.*');
    $this->db->from('rahu AS A');
    $this->db->where('A.status',1);
    return $this->db->get()->result_array();
}
```

this is my controller

```
public function allrecodes()
{
    /*script allow*/
    if (!$this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
        exit('No direct script access allowed here.');
    }

    $response= array();
    $response['result'] = $this->RahuModel->displayRecords();
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

this is my js

```
var get_rec = function(){
        //alert("WWW");
            $.ajax({              
            //request ajax
                url  : "../dashbord/allrecodes",
                type : "post",
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType : "json",
                success: function(dataset) {
                    //var myobject = JSON.stringify(result);
                    //alert(myobject[0]);
                    console.log(dataset);
                    console.log(dataset.result[0]['id']);                       
                },
                 error: function() { alert("Invalide!"); }
            });
    };
```

the json dataset will appear in console.
[image: consol.log]

And also this get_rec() in js file will called top of the page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        //alert("Hello, world!");
        get_rec();});
```

can anyone please help me to fix it.. thank you !!

Comment: I don't see any code trying to put data into table. What did you try?

Comment: can u provide ur `dataset`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "simple" way to do it. You will have to loop through the resultset and render the html.

```
function renderTable(data) {
    var result = ['<table>'];
    var header = false;
    for (var index in data) {
        var row = data[index];
        if (!header) {
            // Create header row.
            header = Object.keys(row);
            var res = ['<tr>'];
            for (var r in header) {
                res.push("<th>" + header[r] + "</th>");
            }
            res.push('</tr>');
            result.push(res.join("\n"));
        }
        // Add data row.
        var res = ['<tr>'];
        for (var r in header) {
            res.push("<td>" + row[header[r]] + "</td>");
        }
        res.push('</tr>');
        result.push(res.join("\n"));
    }
    result.push('</table>');
    return result.join("\n");
}
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = renderTable(data);
```

Have a div tag with id output on your HTML

```
<div id="output"></div>
```